# Dropzone.js will not complete multiple file uploads with https enabled on site...works fine with http

Tags: ssl, iis, dropzone.js

Dropzone will not complete a multiple file upload (it starts but only progresses partially, then stops) when I enable https on a classic asp website. It will still upload 1 file successfully, but only after I clear out other files from the queue or only try to upload 1 at a time. The exact same code works with no problems on http on the same server.

Server is IIS 10.0. I have increased all ASP limits and timeout settings that I am aware of under IIS. I have also made changes to the web.config file to see if it works...all to no avail.

I do not have any "http" references or links in my code.

Here is my dropzone init code settings:

```
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews",
    parallelUploads: 10,
    maxFiles: 10,
    maxFilesize:50, 
    forceFallback: false,
    timeout: 180000,
    dictFileTooBig:'File(s) larger than 50 MB not allowed.',
```

Comment: Before you start the file upload procoss, open the browser developer tool by pressing F12, clear out any existing console messages and networks calls. Then upload file and check for any console error and also api call for file upload and if it is successful

Comment: No console errors. The api is called correctly for each file to upload, however it does not complete any upload. I am wondering if this has something to do with xmlhttprequests over https? However, I have this same script running on other hosted windows environments with https enabled and I am having no issues. Something is not setup correctly on this IIS server...